# Java ParseException when trying to convert Json response into date

Tags: java, json, date, date-format

Currently trying to get my Json response of a date, displayed in a proper date format.
Below is my code followed by the error im getting:

```
String expires = js.getString("expires["+i+"]");

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy hha");
            Date expiration = sdf.parse(expires);
System.out.println(expiration);
```

The error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-08-13T06:37:31Z"

    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at fablemedia.demo.GoDaddyGET.Test(GoDaddyGET.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

How can I fix this?
Thx.

Comment: did u try my answer? It works as expected and is much cleaner

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: What is your expected/desired result?

Comment: @OleV.V.

Really all I need is just the date and year, time is not really too necessary but sure wouldnt hurt to include it

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t clear. I meant, the time in which time zone? It makes a huge difference. Also the date varies: it is never the same day in all time zones. Please learn that when asking for debugging help. always include desired behaviour of your program as precisely as you can.

Comment: @OleV.V. Sry and thx, the timezone is CEST btw

Comment: Great, @Kable. My answer uses CEST. I just edited it to include some explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why are you using The SimpleDateFormatter which is full of bad design and inefficiency.

I would suggest you to use the new DateTime api.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String[] dateArray = new String[10]; // this can be a list as well (containing the date strings or null

    for (String dateStr : dateArray) {
        if (dateStr != null) {
            LocalDateTime parse = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
            String format = parse.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy hha"));
            System.out.println(format);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for this, however I might have forgotten to tell you that im doing this in a foreach loop  * the size of an array, and not all of the elements of the array contains this "expires" value, which causes the following error:
"java.lang.NullPointerException: text", 
On the line: " LocalDateTime parse = LocalDateTime.parse(expires, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);" .

But for the ones containing a value of "expires" it works, so thx for this .

Comment: If it works! I would recommend you to accept the answer please.

Answer (score 1):

> the timezone is CEST btw

**Time zone is crucial.** To output in the desired time zone’s time:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "dd MMMM yyyy hha", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String expires = "2018-08-13T06:37:31Z";
    Instant inst = Instant.parse(expires);
    System.out.println(inst.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Warsaw")).format(formatter));
```

This prints:

> 13 August 2018 08AM

I used Europe/Warsaw as time zone, please pick your own favourite. Many time zones are rendered as CEST in summer, but they are not identical. Poland and other Central European countries are 2 hours ahead of UTC in summer, so the time is given as `08AM` when the expiration string we parsed said `06:37` UTC (the trailing `Z` means Zulu time zone or offset zero or just UTC).

I specified `Locale.ENGLISH` because AM and PM are hardly used in other languages than English, but again, you should make your own pick.

The string to be parsed adheres to ISO 8601 format for a point in time, so I parse it into a Java `Instant` without specifying a formatter. The classes of `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, parse ISO 8601 as their default.

Don’t use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` in 2018. Those classes are long outdated and poorly designed. Particularly `SimpleDateFormat` has a reputation for being troublesome. `java.time` is much nicer to work with.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below dateformat.

```
String expires = "2018-08-13T06:37:31Z";
SimpleDateFormat source = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy hha");

Date expiration = source.parse(expires);

String finalDate = target.format(expiration);
System.out.println(finalDate);
```

Comment: When trying to do this, it prints out the date as "Sun Dec 31 06:37:31 CET 2017".
Which is wrong. Also maybe I should have mentioned that this is inside a foreach loop, and is iterated the size of the array its getting the information from. Furthermore some of the values it goes through does not even have the "expires" value, which causes me a NullPointerException(java.lang.NullPointerException), at the line "Date expiration = sdf.parse(expires);"

Comment: First you have to convert the string to date and then convert the date to the format you want. you skipped the first step that's why you are getting the exception.

Add null check on the expires to avoid the NPE. I updated my answer.

Comment: Totally wrong pattern for source, see the usage of symbols Y (instead of y), D (instead of d) and Z (should not be escaped).

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` is very wrong. You need to watch the case of those letters. And while `T` is a literal, part of the format, `Z` is an offset and should be parsed as such, or you get incorrect results.